# UILabel adjustFont with multiline

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel which usually has to display one or two words.

Many times one of the words doesn't fit into one line, so I would like to reduce font size in order to fit each word at least in one line (not breaking by character).

Using the technique described in http://beckyhansmeyer.com/2015/04/09/autoshrinking-text-in-a-multiline-uilabel/

```
self.numberOfLines = 2;
self.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.minimumScaleFactor = 0.65;
```

I've found that it plays well when the second word doesn't fit in just one line.

[image]

But it doesn't when there is just one word, or the first word is the one
that doesn't fit.
[image][image]

I managed to solve the case of just one word doing this:

```
-(void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    self.numberOfLines =  [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "].count > 1 ? 2 : 1;
    [super setText:text];
}
```

But how could I solve those cases where the first word doesn't fit?? Any ideas?

Comment: try setting `self.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping `

Comment: It doesn't work in any of the cases...

Comment: using autolayout you can easily solve your problem.

Comment: Really? Can you explain how?

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
self.numberOfLines = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "].count;
[self setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
```

But, this will rule out the case where your label text consists of two very small words, eg."how are". In such cases, the entire string will be visible in the first line itself. If it is your requirement to display each word in a separate line then i would recommend you adding a '\n' after every word. This means that you will have to edit the string before assigning it to the label. Thus, a universal solution could be like :

```
NSString *string = @"how are"; //Let this be the string
NSString *modifiedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\n"];
[self setText:modifiedString];
[self setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[self setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
[self setNumberOfLines:0];
self.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Comment: @jdev Please see my edited answer. Also use adjustFontSizeToFitWidth

Comment: Sorry, I just saw you updated your answer when I posted mine and right before yours, so I deleted it. I don't want each word to be displayed in two lines in case they both fit in one line. I need to set numberOfLines to 1, in order to make adjustsFontSize work for one-word-cases, and I'm setting it to 2 when there is more than one word, just in case both words doesn't fit into one line. `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` is already set to YES, so when calling `setText` it should calculate the font size as well.

Comment: I think my dilemma is well represented in the images; When there are two words, and the first one doesn't fit in one line, but the second one does, autoshrink is not reducing the font. If the second word is the one not fitting, autoshrink works just fine.